# How to program multiple WindowsForms at once?

Tags: c#, winforms, for-loop

I got a lot of toolStripMenuItem's, and I want those to all do the same function, but with another parameter. Is this somehow possible to program in a for-loop?

So this is what I got:

```
    private void toolStripMenuItem1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) 
    {
        myFunction(1);
    }

    private void toolStripMenuItem2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        myFunction(2);
    }

    private void toolStripMenuItem3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        myFunction(3);
    }
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Your code is fine. What's the problem? Why a for-loop?

Comment: @ispiro Because I got a lot of buttons(20), I thought it would be nicer if I do this in a for-loop

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Set to OnClick for the 3 controls only one method:

```
private void toolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) 
{
    //I suppose this is MenuItem if it something else you should write correct control

    MenuItem item = (MenuItem)sender;
    int attributeValue = 0;

    if(sender.ID == "toolStripMenuItem1")
    {
        attributeValue=1
    }
    else if (sender.ID == "toolStripMenuItem2")
    {
       attributeValue=2
    }
    else if(sender.ID == "toolStripMenuItem3")
    {
       attributeValue=3
    }

    myFunction(attributeValue);
}
```

If you will have strict names of your controls: toolStripMenuItem1, toolStripMenuItem2 and so on.

```
 MenuItem item = (MenuItem)sender;
 string numberID = string.Concat(item.ID.Where(x=> char.IsNumber(x)));
 myFunction(int.Parse(numberID));
```

Comment: @UweKeim what do you mean by real variables ?

Answer (score 1):

According to your comment, you could iterate over the ToolStripMenu's Children, and subscribe in a for loop. Something like:

```
foreach(ToolStripMenuItem i in toolStripMenu1.Children)
{
    i.Click += toolStripMenuItem_Click;
}
```

and then in `toolStripMenuItem_Click`, have:

```
if(sender as ToolStripMenuItem == toolStripMenuItem1)
{
    ....
}
if(sender as ToolStripMenuItem == toolStripMenuItem2)
{
    ....
}
    ....
```

but there probably wouldn't be any gain in that. The point is that *somewhere* you're going to have to either supply an argument (as in your question's code) or check which item called the method, in order to decide what to do. I'm not saying there **can't** be exceptions. I'm just not finding one easily.